# Difference between lines - awk - linux script

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need some help for one script that I am trying to write. I have one two column array the first column is years and the second values. I want to calculate the difference of the years and when the difference is less than 10, then I want to erase the line of the year that is close to the previous one (in this example the line that contains 1987). I thought that there is a way with awk, but I do not know... i tried some things but they do not work... Thanks just for reading this post, Maria

```
1980  0.5
1987  0.6
2020  0.2
2048  0.6
```

Comment: after `1987` was removed, 2020-1980>10 too, remove 1980 too?  :-)

Comment: @Kent: no—the difference is more than 10 so keep 2020.  If the entry after 1987 was 1992, then the difference from the previous printed value is more than ten but the difference from the previous elided value is only five; what would be correct then?  The goal is probably to have data points that are not less than ten years apart in the output stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$1-prev >= 10 {print; prev=$1}' years.txt
```

This will check if the difference from the first field of the current line is at least 10, and print the line in that case.

Comment: +1: Just have to hope that the first line of data isn't from the first decade AD or last decade BC.  It is unlikely to be a real problem.

Comment: @Maria Glad that I could help. Please accept the answer for future readers.

Comment: I haven't really read the question so I could be off but are you sure that `prev=$1` shouldn't be in its own block outside of the condition so it gets set for every line and not just those for which the condition is true?

Comment: @EdMorton Actually, I think it should be as it is. I understood the post as if the rows should be deleted so that you have as many years as possible, but with a difference of at least 10. Consider the years `1980; 1987; 1991`. In the way you described, both `1987` and `1991` would be deleted. I think the OP wants `1991` to stay. If I misunderstood that, you might be correct.

Comment: Ed Morton thank you for the comment. Tim Zimmermann understood correctly what i am trying to do.